# Use Semantic-UI (or Font Awesome) icons as markers in OpenLayers3

Tags: font-awesome, openlayers-3, semantic-ui

Is there a way to use icons from Semantic UI or FontAwseome as markers icons in OpenLayers3 ?

OpenLayers features the feature style Text that can be used as follows:

```
var blackFill   = new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'})
var whiteStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'white', width: 1})
var iconText    = new ol.style.Text({font: "<my font>", text: "<some string>", fill: blackFill, stroke: whiteStroke })
var featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({ text: iconText });
```

After checking the style of Semantic UI elements, I discovered it is using "Icons" as font-family and escaped characters to choose the symbol (e.g. "\f073" for the calendar icon); therefore I tried (with Semantic-UI's css included in the head section of my page):

```
var iconText    = new ol.style.Text({font: "Icons", text: "\f073", fill: blackFill, stroke: whiteStroke })
```

This merely write "\f073" as markers.
I tried to use "&#xf073", as I would do in HTML, but this shows the same behavior (it writes "&#xf073")
I also tried "\uf073", this showed some square of death indicating an unknown character.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the font to FontAwesome using the font property, like so:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: '\uf041',
    font: 'normal 18px FontAwesome',
    textBaseline: 'Bottom',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'white',
    })
  })
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: This works ! FYI, it works also with Semantic-UI if you specify "Icons" instead of "FontAwesome". Thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to help!  Yeah, the solution is really for any vector icon font you might want to use.  I've been using it myself with Octicons in addition to FontAwesome.

Comment: From Openlayers 4.4.0 and higher, `textBaseline` needs to be `bottom` (lowercase) or it will not work.

Answer (score 9):

I used this code to get it to work with OpenLayers v6.0.1 and Font Awesome 5.11.2:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: '\uf04b',                         // fa-play, unicode f04b
        font: '900 18px "Font Awesome 5 Free"', // font weight must be 900
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Anyone looking to achieve this with Openlayers 6.x and Material Design Icons might find this useful:

```js
const style = new Style({
  text: new Text({
    text: String.fromCodePoint(0xF0470), // the value of the CSS' content property (\ replaced with 0x)
    font: 'normal normal 400 24px "Material Design Icons"'
  }),
})
```

You find the value for the code point in the CSS class for the icon:

```css
.mdi-satellite::before {
  content: "\F0470"; // becomes String.fromCodePoint(0xF0470)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having trouble getting this working, even with the above answer. My problem was that I was directly copying the content typically assigned by FontAwesome in a CSS element instead of the full code.

For example, I was trying to get `fa-chevron-down` to appear using the code `\f077`. However, to get the icon to appear in OpenLayers, you need to use `\uf077`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use canonical names of Font Awesome icons you can use [fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontawesome) package:

```
var fa = require('fontawesome');
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: fa('map-marker'),
    font: 'normal 18px FontAwesome',
    textBaseline: 'Bottom',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'white'
    })
  })
});
```

Node.js example:

```
$ node
> var fa = require("fontawesome");
> fa("map-marker")
''
```