# Changing open layers pointer to an icon

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I want to be able to change the pointer of the mouse to a fontawesome icon and looking at the examples and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809479/use-semantic-ui-or-font-awesome-icons-as-markers-in-openlayers3) , I came up with the following code. But no luck with the code. Here is what I have so far

```
//style for the Map Pointer
   var MapPointer =  new ol.style.Style({
          text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: '\uf040',
          font: 'normal 18px FontAwesome',
          textBaseline: 'Bottom',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'white',
            })
          })
   });


   var features = new ol.Collection();
   var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}),
      style: MapPointer
    });

   featureOverlay.setMap(map);
```

I don't see any changes on the pointer yet. What am I missing ?

Comment: What do you mean with "pointer of the mouse"? Is it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?

Comment: Or do you mean when using the draw interaction?